# Help with Debug Release mode in vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I wrote some basic code to read from the registry with `RegGetValue` which works fine in Debug mode. However in release mode, it fails to read the registry value. There aren't any errors, it just doesn't work.  What can I do to make this function work in release mode? (Windows 7 x64, VS 2008)

```
DWORD sz, regval=0; 
RegCreateKeyEx(
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    _T("Software\\App"),
    0,
    NULL,
    REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
    KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &sz);
RegGetValue(
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
    _T("Software\\App"),
    _T("Value"),
    RRF_RT_ANY,
    NULL,
    &regval,
    &sz);
```

Comment: DWORD sz,regval=0;
RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,_T("Software\\App"),0,NULL,REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS ,NULL,NULL,&sz); 
 RegGetValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,_T("Software\\App"),_T("Value"),RRF_RT_ANY,NULL,&regval,&sz);

Comment: In your question.  Having no clue how SO works is no longer a reasonable excuse.

Answer (score 0):

Define how this code "works fine" in Debug mode.

This code adds a key and then reads a value underneath it, but there is no code to add a value.

If this is the full code then you need to add a value named "Value" before trying to read it.  See [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724923%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for how to do this.

It looks like the code above will not correctly retrieve the value because `sz` has to be set on input to indicate how large a buffer is available. Hard to tell without full code but since this value is `REG_DWORD` this would be `sz = sizeof(DWORD);`, for example.

Comment: okay, some clarification as to my question. i am using RegQueryValueEx to read an existing registry key (REG_DWORD) the function returns success, however the buffer (LPBYTE lpData) contains no data.furthermore, the output buffer containing the value size of the data buffer (LPDWORD lpcbData) does give me the size of the data. this problem is only in release mode, in debug, it properly return the buffer data.

Comment: The code above will not correctly retrieve the value because `sz` has to be set on input to indicate how large a buffer is available.  Hard to tell without full code but since this value is REG_DWORD this would be `sz = sizeof(DWORD);`, for example.

Comment: Thanx! that was the problem. sz was uninitialized, just created. i think the reason it was working in debug mode is because when creating a variable (DWORD sz) it is filled with a value (as opposed to 0) so RegQueryValueEx was using the default value of sz.

Comment: Glad this helped.  I'll add that into the answer instead of as a comment.